# Get max and min value in a group of strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
values = [5, 6,7,8 , 9, 11,12, 13, 14, 17, 18,19, 20, 21,22, 23, 
          24, 25, 26, 27, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47]
s = pd.Series(values)
s1 = s.groupby(s.diff().gt(1).cumsum()).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
print (s1)
```

> 0:                           5,6,7,8,9
>
> 1:                         11,12,13,14
>
> 2:    17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27
>
> 3:                               41,42
>
> 4:                         44,45,46,47

I am trying to find the `min` and `max` of each line of the group. I have tried several approaches, but I don't get it correctly.

My belief is, it has to be converted to `int`, then the maximum and minimum can be found, but I am not sure how to do that. Every time I try to access the series it converts to strings.

The output will be in a form of `min` and `max` value in the following `for` loop:

```
for num in s1:
    min_value = 
    max_value = 
    print(min_value ,max_value )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest create `list`s instead joined `string`s and then use `min` and `max`:

```
s1 = s.groupby(s.diff().gt(1).cumsum()).apply(list)
print (s1)
0                                 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1                                [11, 12, 13, 14]
2    [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
3                                        [41, 42]
4                                [44, 45, 46, 47]
dtype: object

for num in s1:
    min_value = min(num)
    max_value = max(num)
    print(min_value ,max_value)
```

Or better use `groupby` object and first join to `string`s and then aggregate `min` and `max`:

```
g = s.groupby(s.diff().gt(1).cumsum())
s1 = g.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
print (s1)
0                           5,6,7,8,9
1                         11,12,13,14
2    17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27
3                               41,42
4                         44,45,46,47
dtype: object

s1 = g.agg([min, max])
print (s1)
   min  max
0    5    9
1   11   14
2   17   27
3   41   42
4   44   47
```

But if need working with `joined` strings is possible split and convert to `int`, last get `min` and `max`:

```
s1 = s.groupby(s.diff().gt(1).cumsum()).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
print (s1)
0                           5,6,7,8,9
1                         11,12,13,14
2    17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27
3                               41,42
4                         44,45,46,47
dtype: object

for line in s1:
    a = [int(x) for x in line.split(',')]
    min_value = min(a)
    max_value = max(a)
    print(min_value ,max_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion:

```
import pandas as pd

values = [5, 6,7,8 , 9, 11,12, 13, 14, 17, 18,19, 20, 21,22, 23, 
          24, 25, 26, 27, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47]
s = pd.Series(values)
s1 = s.groupby(s.diff().gt(1).cumsum()).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))

for line in s1:
    print("{} -> max: {}, min: {}".format(line, max(line.split(',')), min(line.split(','))))

 '''
5,6,7,8,9 -> max: 9, min: 5
11,12,13,14 -> max: 14, min:  11 
17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27 -> max: 27, min: 17        
41,42 -> max: 42, min: 41                                     
44,45,46,47 -> max: 47, min: 44                             
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the s1

```
s2=s1.str.split(',',expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric)
s2.max(1)
Out[29]: 
0     9.0
1    14.0
2    27.0
3    42.0
4    47.0
dtype: float64
s2.min(1)
Out[30]: 
0     5.0
1    11.0
2    17.0
3    41.0
4    44.0
dtype: float64
```

If you like int , you can adding `astype(int)` at the end

Comment: just to keep in mind that this changes the datatype to `float` from `int` which is fine if OP's data consists of the same

Comment: @Kevad then we can adding astype(int) at the end

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do with `apply` function

```
min_max = s1.apply(lambda x: (min(map(int, x.split(','))), 
                              max(map(int, x.split(',')))))

for min_, max_ in min_max:
  print (min_, max_)
```

execution time:

```
In [10]: timeit s1.apply(lambda x: (min(map(int, x.split(','))), max(map(int, x.split(',')))))
109 µs ± 445 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```